# How to create a scrollable div with padding on top and bottom without extra markup on the inside?

Tags: html, css

[I have created a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w3gL7/) to illustrate my question. Basically I'd like to have a container with scrollable content that has a padding on the top and the bottom. [Edit:] This padding should be visible while scrolling, so that at any given time you have the same distance from the edge to the content.

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- pure content, no extra wrapper -->
    <h1>This is how I'd like it</h1>
    <p> ... </p>
</div>
```

I can only achieve the effect by adding an extra wrapper to the inside of the container. Does anyone know of another workaround that doesn't introduce another element?

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- extra wrapper, me unhappy -->
    <div class="inner">
        <h1>This is how I can do it</h1>
        <p> ... </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For me and FF6, your "looking bad, desired markup" looks good.

Comment: Same here, in Chrome 14, Firefox 6, Opera 11.50, Safari 5.1, and (surprisingly) Internet Explorer 9.

Comment: For me it looks good as well - for the first look. But then I realized, that you want the padding to be there, even when you are scrolling. I'm afraid, that's not possible without the extra wrapper.

Comment: Right, I'd like the padding even when scrolling, so there's always the same distance to the edges. I'm afraid I'll have to use the wrapper :)

Comment: I know what are you looking for. I tried `:before` and `:after` and also css `clip` but none of them worked. I feel it's impossible to not have another `div` wrapping the scrolled `div`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution I could think of is adding a thick border around the box of same background color as that of the box, and reducing width/height accordingly.
[Thickness of border = required padding on any side] & [border color = background color of the box ]

Comment: Good point! The only thing is that you have to choose solid colors for background or using not widely supported border-image

Comment: This is as close as ist gets. Tranks for your contribution.

Comment: or use `border-color:rgba(0,0,0,0)`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following CSS.

```
.container {
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    height: 80px; /* Set your desired value here */
    width: 200px; /* Set your desired value here */
    overflow-x: scroll; /* for horizontal scroll-bar */    
    overflow-y: scroll; /* for vertical scroll-bar */
    white-space: nowrap; /* needed only if you want to disable text-wrapping. */
}
```

Comment: While this creates a scrollable container, the padding will only be visible when you have scrolled to the top or the bottom. When you're in the middle of the content, the content will hit the edges of the container and that's the thing I want to avoid.